# SMS Receiver not working in MIUI (Xiaomi 2014818 Android 4.4.4,API19)

Tags: android

I am working on android application in which User have to registered after OTP verification but It is working on other mobile except MIUI any version like(Xiaomi 2014818 Android 4.4.4,API19).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MI devices can set permissions per app. Check if the app has SMS permission enabled.

I am not saying about the manifest permission. I think to need to go to Settings > Apps > {your_app} > permissions and check if the SMS permission is enabled. As Xiaomi phones provide per app permissions. Please check if there is a tick and not a question mark for SMS as in the following image.

[image]

Comment: I have already provide sms receiver  and sms read permission.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: @Bansal hey if it has helped you, could you please accept my answer.